# Joining shape's data to GPS's attribute table using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a GPS shapefile that looks like this

[image]

and I have landcover shape that has the type of forests and it looks like this

[image]

What I want to do is to add to tha attribute table of the GPS shape the type of forest that the GPS crosses.

Like in this example

[image]

For all the GPS points intersecting the green zone of the landcover shape I want to add to the GPS attribute table the type of the forest that the GPS point intersects (in my example "foret fermée de hetre pur").

I can't use join because I don't have a column in common between the GPS file and the land cover file and I can't use merge because the GPS type and the landcover type of geometry doesn't match.

I am using ArcMap.

Comment: ArcGIS has a function like "join attributes by location". See here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/about-joining-the-attributes-of-features-by-their-location.htm

Comment: Intersect between a point and a polygon will add the polygon attributes to the points.

Comment: If you intend to do much analysis of this data, you should probably convert your points to lines. There are geoprocessing tools that do that, but I am no longer very familiar with them. Also GPS data has lots of crossovers and ugliness, so also look at the Check/Repair Geometry GP tools.

Comment: Please always decide which of QGIS and ArcMap you wish to ask about in a particular question. You tagged both and mentioned neither in your question body but your pictures are of ArcMap. You can always ask about the other in a separate question.